# Textbox, search without accents (ignore accents)

Tags: c#, search, windows-phone

My Windows Phone app have a ListBox (populated from a JSON) and a TextBox used to search items on the ListBox.

This code works fine, but I need be able to search "lapis" and find "lápis". 
So, I need ignore accents on my search.

How do it?

```
        private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Items != null)
        {
            this.List1.ItemsSource = Items.Where(w => w.descricao.ToUpper().Contains(SearchTextBox.Text.ToUpper()));
        }
    }

    private void WatermarkTB_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SearchTextBox.Text == "Pesquisar Produto...")
        {
            SearchTextBox.Text = "";
            SolidColorBrush Brush1 = new SolidColorBrush();
            Brush1.Color = Colors.Red;
            SearchTextBox.Foreground = Brush1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
w.descricao.ToUpper().Contains(SearchTextBox.Text.ToUpper())
```

To

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(
    w.descricao, 
    SearchTextBox.Text, 
    CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) != -1
```

The meaning of `IgnoreNonSpace`

> Indicates that the string comparison must ignore nonspacing combining characters, such as diacritics.

Comment: I did as you say, but when I click in textbox, the ListBox is blank.

Comment: @ReneSá Sorry - I overlooked the `Contains` part. Now it get's a little more complicated, but still a one-liner. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Extension method:

```
public static string RemoveDiacritic(this string text)
{
    return text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Where(chara => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(chara) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark).Aggregate<char, string>(null, (current, character) => current + character);
}
```

Usage:

```
this.List1.ItemsSource = Items.Where(w => w.descricao.ToUpper().RemoveDiacritic().Contains(SearchTextBox.Text.ToUpper().RemoveDiacritic()));
```